# Why is a full circle 360° degrees?

Tags: soft-question

What's the reason we agreed to setting the number of degrees of a full circle to 360? Does that make any more sense than 100, 1000 or any other number? Is there any logic involved in that particular number?

Comment: Speculation about why the degree was chosen as it was can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degree_(angle)#History).

Comment: I think you can probably blame the Babylonians, who loved to count in base 60, but this should probably be moved to the maths site. You're more likely to find a math history expert there. :)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/142735/11127

Answer (score 35, accepted):

As it has been replied [here - on Wonder Quest](https://web.archive.org/web/20130520192640/http://www.wonderquest.com/circle.htm) (webarchive link):

> The Sumerians watched the Sun, Moon, and the five visible planets
> (Mercury, Venus, Mars, Jupiter, and Saturn), primarily for omens. They
> did not try to understand the motions physically. They did, however,
> notice the circular track of the Sun's annual path across the sky and
> knew that **it took about 360 days to complete one year's circuit**.
> Consequently, they divided the **circular path into 360 degrees** to track
> each day's passage of the Sun's whole journey. This *probably happened
> about 2400 BC*.
>
> That's how we got a 360 degree circle. Around 1500 BC, Egyptians
> divided the day into 24 hours, though the hours varied with the
> seasons originally. Greek astronomers made the hours equal. About 300
> to 100 BC, the **Babylonians subdivided the hour into base-60 fractions:
> 60 minutes in an hour and 60 seconds in a minute**. The base 60 of their
> number system lives on in our time and angle divisions.
>
> An 100-degree circle makes sense for base 10 people like ourselves.
> But the base-60 Babylonians came up with 360 degrees and we cling to
> their ways-4,400 years later.

Then, there's also this discussion [on Math Forum](https://web.archive.org/web/20171216013318/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/59075.html):

> In 1936, a tablet was excavated some 200 miles from Babylon. Here one
> should make the interjection that the Sumerians were first to make one
> of man's greatest inventions, namely, writing; through written
> communication, knowledge could be passed from one person to others,
> and from one generation to the next and future ones.  They impressed
> their cuneiform (wedge-shaped) script on soft clay tablets with a
> stylus, and the tablets were then hardened in the sun.  The mentioned
> tablet, whose translation was partially published only in 1950, is
> devoted to various geometrical figures, and states that the ratio of
> the perimeter of a regular hexagon to the circumference of the
> circumscribed circle equals a number which in modern notation is given
> by $ \frac{57}{60} + \frac{36}{60^2} $
> (the Babylonians used the sexagesimal system, i.e., their
> base was 60 rather than 10).
>
> The Babylonians knew, of course, that the perimeter of a hexagon is
> exactly equal to six times the radius of the circumscribed circle, in
> fact that was evidently the reason why they chose to divide the circle
> into 360 degrees (and we are still burdened with that figure to this
> day).  The tablet, therefore, gives ... $\pi = \frac{25}{8} = 3.125$.

Comment: While it seems likely that 360 is related to the number of days, I would like to know what exactly would be meant by "the circular track of the Sun's annual path across the sky".

Comment: @MarekFekete perhaps they are referring to the ecliptic motion of the sun?